# JTable cell changes when clicking Button?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I have a table with a tablemodel containg some names and a CellRenderer which extends a Panel I made which contains a JButton. Everythign works great except when I click on the button the values in the Cell disappear as long as I hold the JButton clicked!? bellow the Panel and the Renderer. Any ideas?

```
        package gui.table;

    import event.TestController;
    import gui.DaimlerColor;
    import gui.MainWindow;

    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

    import org.jdom2.Document;
    import org.jdom2.Element;


    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class TestcaseCellRenderer extends TestcasePanel implements TableCellRenderer {

        List<String> data;
        MainWindow gui = null;
        TestController tgc = null;

        public TestcaseCellRenderer() {
            super();
            setName("Table.cellRenderer");
        }

        public TestcaseCellRenderer(List<String> names, MainWindow gui2, TestController tgc) {
            super();
            this.data = names;
            this.gui = gui2;
            this.tgc = tgc;
            setName("Table.cellRenderer");
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

            //this.setBackground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table
            //      .getBackground());

            this.setOpaque(true);
            this.setToolTipText("Click play to rerun this Testcase");

            this.setName(data.get(row));

            //set Button Image if passed
            int passed = 0;

            setPlaybuttonIcon(gui.getTestcasetableModelIcon(row));

            setClickable(tgc.clickable);


            if (row <= gui.currentTestcase) {
                Document doc = tgc.getDoc();
                List<Element> cases = doc.getRootElement().getChildren();
                List<Element> teststeps = cases.get(row).getChildren();
                List<String> attributes = new LinkedList();
                for (Element teststep : teststeps) {


                    if (teststep.getAttribute("status") != null) {
                        attributes.add(teststep.getAttributeValue("status"));
                    }
                    else{
                        attributes.add("empty");
                    }

                }
                if(attributes.contains("empty")){
                    setButton("");
                }
                else if (attributes.contains("failed")){

                    setButton("failed");
                }
                else{
                    setButton("passed");
                }

            } else {
                setButton("");
            }

            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            this.setBackground(isSelected ?  DaimlerColor.LIGHT_BLUE : (row % 2 == 1 ? DaimlerColor.DARK_WHITE : DaimlerColor.WHITE));
            return this;
        }


    }



    package gui.table;
import gui.MainWindow;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestcasePanel extends JPanel {
    public  JButton playButton = new JButton();// new JButton("Play");
    //
    String name = "-";
    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel(name);
    JLabel statusIconLabel = new JLabel();
    public MainWindow gui;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        nameLabel.setText(name);
    }

    public void setClickable(boolean b){
        playButton.setEnabled(b);
    }

    public void setPlaybuttonIcon(String s){
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ressources\\playbutton.png");
        Image img = icon.getImage();
        Image scaledImg = img.getScaledInstance(16, 16, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        icon = new ImageIcon(scaledImg);


        ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ressources\\pausebutton.png");
        Image img2 = icon2.getImage();
        Image scaledImg2 = img2.getScaledInstance(16, 16, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        icon2 = new ImageIcon(scaledImg2);

        if(s.equals("play")){
            playButton.setIcon(icon);
        }else{
            playButton.setIcon(icon2);
        }
    }

    public void setButton(String s) {

        if (s.equals("passed")) {
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ressources\\check.png");
            Image img = icon.getImage();
            icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            statusIconLabel.setIcon(icon);
            statusIconLabel.setOpaque(false);

        } else if (s.equals("failed")) {
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ressources\\fail.png");
            Image img = icon.getImage();
            icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            statusIconLabel.setIcon(icon);
            statusIconLabel.setOpaque(false);

        } else {
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ressources\\help.png");
            Image img = icon.getImage();
            icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            statusIconLabel.setIcon(icon);
            statusIconLabel.setOpaque(false);

        }
    }

    public TestcasePanel() {
        super();
        setOpaque(true);

        playButton.setFocusable(false);
        playButton.setRolloverEnabled(false);
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        this.setLayout(gbl);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbl.setConstraints(statusIconLabel, gbc);
        this.add(statusIconLabel);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0.8;
        gbl.setConstraints(nameLabel, gbc);
        this.add(nameLabel);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ressources\\playbutton.png");
        Image img = icon.getImage();
        Image scaledImg = img.getScaledInstance(Integer.valueOf((int) this.getPreferredSize().getHeight()).intValue(),
                Integer.valueOf((int) this.getPreferredSize().getHeight()).intValue(), java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        icon = new ImageIcon(scaledImg);
        playButton.setName("play");
        playButton.setIcon(icon);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbl.setConstraints(playButton, gbc);
        this.add(playButton);

    }

    public void setButtonIcon(String name){

        if(name.equals("play")){
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ressources\\playbutton.png");
            Image img = icon.getImage();
            Image scaledImg = img.getScaledInstance(16,16, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            icon = new ImageIcon(scaledImg);
            playButton.setIcon(icon);


        }else if (name.equals("pause")) {
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ressources\\pausebutton.png");
            Image img = icon.getImage();
            Image scaledImg =  img.getScaledInstance(16,16, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            icon = new ImageIcon(scaledImg);
            playButton.setIcon(icon);


        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: the renderer looks suspiciously active - it must not do anything else than _rendering_ the given value ...

Comment: http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html

Answer (score 2):

- don't to set/modify any `JComponent`, its value inside `XxxRenderer`, don't to change state of value (came from `XxxTableModel`)
- `XxxRenderer` is only decorator not value generator,
- for cell value (in `XxxRenderer`) is resposible value stored in `XxxTableModel`, to set this value in `XxxTableModel`,
- don't store `JComponents` in `XxxTableModel`, there is stored only its rendering value

Answer (score 0):

Your renderer is a whole component that has a button and everything. I believe this is not the correct way to implement a renderer. This behaviour needs to be simulated e.g.

- In the table's `MouseListener` find where the user clicked and what row needs to be changed
- Update your table model accordingly
- Fire an event to let the table know that it should re-draw the updated cell
- The cell renderer will be executed again and draw cell's new state.

You use some imports from the `gui` package that prevents the code to compile and run so my best guess here would be that the button messes with the rendering while is being pressed -perhaps when trying to draw its pressed state?